# Getting Multiple Inputs in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this Python 3 code template in a coding website. The site claims that `t` will be a string of `n` integers.

```py
n = int(input())
for i in input().split():
    t = int(i)
```

I understand `input.split()` is for taking multiple inputs, like in `a, b = input.split()` will raise a `ValueError` until I give two inputs like `1 2`.

What I don't understand is how it is implemented in a for-loop. Like, what value does `i` take on? And how Python is supposed to know that `t` will have `n` integers?

**NOTE:** I tried printing `t`. The result is as same as `t = int(input())`. I am not getting this. Please help.

Comment: `n` is unused in your code. Your loop will go through however many numbers are in the string you input. Presumably, in the expected input, there will be `n` numbers in the string.

Comment: This code, as it is now, does **not** create a list of integers. It merely splits the input on space and converts individual digits to integers

Comment: You said "I tried printing `t`. The result is as same as `t = int(input())`". Really? Did you try to input a value with more than one digit e.g. `123`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks. I got it!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? "Like, what value does ``i`` take on?" – you can just test that, e.g. via ``print``. "And how Python is supposed to know that t will have n integers?" – you can also test that, e.g. by inputing an `n=4` followed by 6 values.

Comment: @Matthias 'Did you try to input a value with more than one digit e.g. 123' Are you saying more than 1 number e.g. `123 456`? Because a single number input no matter how many digits it has gives the same output as `t = int(input())`. Whereas, then I tried a multi-input, the last input got printed. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'm clear now.

Comment: @Jenkins `@DeepSpace Thanks. I got it!` - uh, only I didn't ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found this Python 3 code template in a coding website. The site claims that t will be a string of n integers.

If this is really the case, I recommend you to contact the owner of the website, because this statement is **wrong**, already by definition : A string is the ***contrary*** of an integer in Python. For an explanation of the code see below.

```py
n = int(input())
for i in input().split():
    t = int(i)
```

This code lets you first input a number `n`, which is never used.
Then, it lets you input a string containing numbers separated by spaces, splits the string at spaces and loops over the resulting list. Each item is converted to int, and assigned to a variable `t`, which, in the end, get's garbage collected because it is never used.